# one query, one table, two count()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if username and email taken in my registration script.

This is how I check with query:

```
$emailcheck = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS nume FROM members WHERE email = :email";
//bindValue
//execute
//fetch
if($rowe['nume'] > 0){
$errors[] = "E-mail exist.";
}
```

And also I'm doing the same thing for username;

```
$usercheck = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS numu FROM members WHERE username = :username";
//bindValue
//execute
//fetch
if($rowu['numu'] > 0){
$errors[] = "Username taken.";
}
```

*

I want to go one step further and handle all of stuff with one query.

But I couldn't came up with such query.

I tried:

```
$check = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS numu and COUNT(email) AS nume FROM members WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
```

but probably It's ridiculous.

How to handle what I want with one query?

And after I want to check like that:

```
if($row['numu'] > 0){
$errors[] = "Username taken.";
} 
if($rowe['nume'] > 0){
$errors[] = "E-mail exist.";
}
```

So it will be less code, instead of connecting same table twice and `bindValue, execute, fetch` for second time.

Comment: Where (username =usrrname OR email = email) .. try

Comment: As you can see there in my post, i tried it sir :)

Comment: no little difference add both clause in one bracket

Comment: As with normal SELECT list you separate the items by comas `SELECT COUNT(username) AS numu, COUNT(email) AS nume FROM ...`

Comment: @devpro, sorry my bad. This time it tells me both email and username exist when there is only one of them exist. @ Tristan, thanks, fixed that part. ;)

Comment: "But probably it's ridiculous"... why? `SELECT COUNT(username) AS numu and COUNT(email) AS nume FROM members WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";`  seems to me numu would tell you if someone as the ID already and nume would tell you if someone had the email address already.  why didn't this work?

Comment: I thought it's ridicilious on the beginning because kind of I came up with this code by myself with no great mysql background. However, this code currently telling me both username and email exist when only one of them is exist. So still need a little touch. I also tried to change `OR` to `AND` but this time didn't work at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do `Union All` to unite those queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(email) AS num FROM members WHERE email = :email
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM members WHERE username = :username
```

Then extract 2 according rows.

OR, MySQL allows this thing:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(email) FROM members WHERE email = :email) as nume,
    (SELECT COUNT(username) FROM members WHERE username = :username) as numu
```

if you want 1 rows with 2 columns.

Do that only if you need to see which one is already present. Otherwise just do this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM members WHERE email = :email OR username = :username LIMIT 1
```

Yes, consider not doing `count()` because you don't need to count all the rows. You just need to stop if you find just one. So either do a `LIMIT` or `IF EXISTS()`

Comment: I tried second block of your code and it actually search for results in two rows and it works. So I'm writing this lines for future learners. Also thanks for `LIMIT` tip.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you really need to count. Assuming you want to check if either username or email already exist because they are required to be unique on your user table, you can do this:

First, add a unique index to each of those columns in your database. You may already have this, but if you want those values to be unique, this will ensure that even if your PHP code fails to do so for some reason.

Then you can use this query:

```
SELECT username, email FROM members WHERE username = :username OR email = :email
```

This will return either zero, one, or two rows, where:

- 0 = neither username nor email was found
- 1 = one row was found having either username, email, or both
- 2 = username was found in one row and email was found in another

Then you can loop over your results, comparing them to the user input, and set your errors.

```
while ($row = //fetch) {
    if ($row['username'] == $username) {
        $errors[] = "Username taken.";
    } 
    if ($row['email'] == $email) {
        $errors[] = "E-mail exist.";
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1, but needs some mentions: When you compare in the DB, you're probably working in the usual CI collation, so 'Alex'='alex' will evaluate to true, as opposed to PHP, where the comparison is binary. Thus, you have to take care of this issue in PHP, and make sure the algorithm matches the collation from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after removing `and` between count

```
   $check = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS uname , 
       COUNT(email) AS uemail FROM members 
       WHERE (username = :username OR email = :email)";
```

Comment: This time It tells me both username and email exist in the database, when there is only one of them is exist.